# VBA count rows between rows based on two criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to count distance (row count) between changes for each id for a dataset like this:

```
change  id  distance
1   id 1    
1   id 1    
1   id 1    
1   id 1    
0   id 1    4
1   id 1    1
1   id 1    
1   id 1    
1   id 1    
0   id 2    
0   id 2    
0   id 2    
1   id 2    3
```

Right now I have a code that puts distance as an overall count of rows, not on id level. Can someone help me with that?

```
Sub cnt()
    For i = 3 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = CStr(i - 2)
        End If
    Next i
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are always comparing i to row 2.

```
Cells(i, 3).Value = CStr(i - 2)
```

That "2" needs to change every time there is a change or the id is different. I would do something like this (the explicit variable declarations are because I've been burned by Excel/VBA for not doing that in the past).

```
Option Explicit

Sub cnt()
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set targetRange = currentSheet.UsedRange

    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    x = 2
    With targetRange
        For i = 3 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = CStr(i - x)
                x = i
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 2).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
                x = i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun,

Here is a formula that does what you want.

Put this in C2 and copy/drag down:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>A1,B2=B1),ROW(1:1)-MATCH(B2,B:B,0)+1-SUMIF($B$1:B1,B2,$C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]